# php json_encode in js returning undesired result

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to pass an array from php to JavaScript. But in js the array values are being read as each individual char.
My code;

```
<?php
$arr=array(1=>'apple', 2=>'ball');
$garr=json_encode($arr);
?>

<script>
var ax = '<?php echo $garr; ?>';
alert(ax.length);
for(var n=0;n<ax.length; n++)alert(ax[n]);
</script>
```

The result is lenght=23 and each char as output.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ax` is `string`. You need to convert the string representation in `json` format.
Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert string to json.

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing.

```
var ax = JSON.parse('<?php echo $garr; ?>'); // ax is not JSON object
```

Comment: both you and @VolkerK are right. needed json.parse AND not return object

Answer (score 1):

The output of json_encode() for your php array is

```
{"1":"apple","2":"ball"}
```

that's an object literal. But you want an array. Try it with:

```
$arr=array(0=>'apple', 1=>'ball');
```

And remove the single-quotes, they mark a string literal and you don't want `ax` to be a string but an array/object.

```
var ax = <?php echo $garr; ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just printing a JSON string, this way ax will be nothing more than a string.

Use a parser, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
```

If you're using JQuery use [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
jQuery.parseJSON( jsonString );
```

Comment: Reverse is `str = JSON.stringify(obj);`